# How to remove default header from WordPress theme?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I updated a theme that was in use on my client's website, and now the original default header has appeared and displays the name of the page on all pages. This is looking scruffy and interferes with the overall layout of the site and I would like to remove it.

See - http://bulldog-breeders.co.uk/

**[Theme Header PHP]**

```
<?php /**  * @package Dusk_To_Dawn  */ ?>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <!--[if IE 8]> <html id="ie8" <?php language_attributes(); ?>> <![endif]-->
  <!--[if !(IE 8)]><!-->
  <html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
  <!--<![endif]-->

  <head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
    <title>
      <?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?>
    </title>
    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
    <!--[if lt IE 9]> <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <![endif]-->
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
  </head>

  <body <?php body_class(); ?>>
    <div id="super-super-wrapper">
      <div id="super-wrapper">
        <div id="wrapper">
          <?php do_action( 'before' ); ?>
            <div id="page" class="hfeed">
              <header id="branding" role="banner">
                <hgroup>
                  <h1 id="site-title"><a href="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
                  <h2 id="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>
                </hgroup>
              </header>
              <!-- #branding -->

              <div id="main" class="clear-fix">
                <?php
                            // Do we have a header image around?
                            if ( '' != get_header_image() ) :
                        ?>
                  <div id="header-image">
                    <a href="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
                                <img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" alt="" />
                            </a>
                  </div>
                  <?php endif; ?>
```

**[Custom Header PHP]**

```
<?php /**  * Sample implementation of the Custom Header feature  * http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Headers  *  * You can add an optional custom header image to header.php like so ...

    <?php $header_image = get_header_image();   if ( ! empty( $header_image ) ) { ?> <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home">           <img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" alt="" />         </a>
  <?php } // if ( ! empty( $header_image ) ) ?>

    * * @package Dusk To Dawn */ /** * Setup the WordPress core custom header feature. * * @uses dusk_to_dawn_header_style() * @uses dusk_to_dawn_admin_header_style() * @uses dusk_to_dawn_admin_header_image() * * @package Dusk To Dawn */ function dusk_to_dawn_custom_header_setup()
    { add_theme_support( 'custom-header', apply_filters( 'dusk_to_dawn_custom_header_args', array( 'default-image' => '', 'default-text-color' => '497ca7', 'width' => 870, 'height' => 220, 'wp-head-callback' => 'dusk_to_dawn_header_style', 'admin-head-callback'
    => 'dusk_to_dawn_admin_header_style', 'admin-preview-callback' => 'dusk_to_dawn_admin_header_image', ) ) ); } add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'dusk_to_dawn_custom_header_setup' ); if ( ! function_exists( 'dusk_to_dawn_header_style' ) ) : /** * Styles
    the header image and text displayed on the blog * * @see dusk_to_dawn_custom_header_setup(). */ function dusk_to_dawn_header_style() { $header_text_color = get_header_textcolor(); // If no custom options for text are set, let's bail // get_header_textcolor()
    options: HEADER_TEXTCOLOR is default, hide text (returns 'blank') or any hex value if ( HEADER_TEXTCOLOR == $header_text_color ) return; // If we get this far, we have custom styles. Let's do this. ?>
    <style type="text/css">
      <?php // Has the text been hidden?        if ( 'blank' == $header_text_color ) :  ?>      #branding hgroup,       #site-title,        #site-description {             position: absolute;             clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); /* IE6, IE7 */             clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);         }       #page {             padding: 132px 0 0 0;       }   <?php       // If the user has set a custom color for the text use that         else :  ?>      #site-title a {             color: #<?php echo $header_text_color; ?>;      }   <?php endif; ?>

    </style>
    <?php } endif; // dusk_to_dawn_header_style

if ( ! function_exists( 'dusk_to_dawn_admin_header_style' ) ) : /**  * Styles the header image displayed on the Appearance > Header admin panel.  *  * @see dusk_to_dawn_custom_header_setup().  */ function dusk_to_dawn_admin_header_style() { ?>
      <style type="text/css">
        #headimg {
          width: <?php echo get_custom_header()->width;
          ?>px;
          height: <?php echo get_custom_header()->height;
          ?>px;
        }

        #heading,
        #headimg h1,
        #headimg #desc {
          display: none;
        }

      </style>
      <?php } endif; // dusk_to_dawn_admin_header_style

if ( ! function_exists( 'dusk_to_dawn_admin_header_image' ) ) : /**  * Custom header image markup displayed on the Appearance > Header admin panel.  *  * @see dusk_to_dawn_custom_header_setup().  */ function dusk_to_dawn_admin_header_image() {     $header_image = get_header_image(); ?>
        <div id="headimg">
          <?php if ( ! empty( $header_image ) ) : ?> <img src="<?php echo esc_url( $header_image ); ?>" alt="" />
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        <?php } endif; // dusk_to_dawn_admin_header_image
```

Comment: The code you provided is irrelevant. I would guess this is most likely found in `page.php`, look for `<h1 class="entry-title">`. I would not advise you to remove this if you really care about SEO and accessibility, otherwise wrap the titles in your content pages inside an `h1` heading...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that your problem is in the header.php file. If it is the entry title that you are wanting to hide you could find where it is being printed in the other PHP files and remove that line of code.

Or, you could simply use a display:none on the entry title class in the styles.css.

Example:
    h1 .entry-title {
      display:none;
    }

Answer (score 0):

In the place of get_header(); function you can call your custom header file.
that will remove default header and added your header just like if you create your new header file named custom-header.php

then call it like

```
<?php echo get_header('custom');?>
```